# How to extract the year from a column with different date formatted strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe column with different types of **strings** that look like this:

```
    year
0   1990
1   1998.0
2   2006-02-12
```

I want to only extract the year only from them all and convert them to either `int` or `float`.

```
    year
0   1990
1   1998
2   2006
```

Comment: something like a `left(4)` might do the trick?

Comment: Are those the only patterns you have?

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those are the only patterns, you can use [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=['1990','1998.0','2006-02-12'], columns=['year'])

result = df.year.str.extract('^(\d{4})')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
      0
0  1990
1  1998
2  2006
```

The pattern `^(\d{4})` translates to the first 4 digits at the beginning string, so you are basically extracting the first 4 digits of each string in the column.

Comment: I also tried this and it worked: `df['year'].apply(lambda x: x[:4])`

Comment: Or `df.year.str.slice(0, 4)` :)

Comment: @BKS you can also do `df.year.str[:4]`